# Can't save to plist

Tags: objective-c

I have my own object class from inherited from NSObject

```
@interface BlockedCell : NSObject 
{
    NSValue *gridValue;
    NSString *name;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSValue *gridValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

So I try to create a few objects:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[dict alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    BlockedCell *block = [[BlockedCell alloc] init];
    block.gridValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
    block.name = @"something";
    [dict setObject: block forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"item_%d", i]];
    [block release];
}

if([dict writeToFile: path atomic: YES])
   NSLog(@"Saved");
else
   NSLog(@"Failed to save");

[dict release];
```

And what I get for the output is "Failed to save"..
If my dictionary does not contains any data, then it will output "Saved"

EDIT:
After I did more testing, I found out that actually is the NSValue causing the saving failed.
So what should I do if I want to save CGPoint into plist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, property lists cannot store `NSValue` objects directly.  The supported classes are NSData, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, and NSNumber, as documented in the [*NSPropertyListSerialization Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The easiest workaround would be to use `NSString` instead of `NSValue`:

```
block.gridString = NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointZero);

CGPoint point = CGPointFromString(block.gridString);
```

Comment: Thanks, very well explained :)

Answer (score 1):

you cant save NSValue directly.In your case you have to save a point  in the form ofstring use below line

CGPoint point  = CGPointMake(10.0,20.0)
//you need to translate the point into a compatible "Plist" object such as NSString
//luckily, there is a method for that

[rectArray addObject:NSStringFromPoint(point)];

//save into a plist
.....

on retrieval of this value

CGPoint Point = CGPointFromString([rectArray objectAtIndex:0]);